# Flutter Drawer Overlaps the bottom Navigation bar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

[image]----------

Here is the 1st-screenshot of my problem
[image]

This is the 2nd-second screenshot when after implementing single child scrolled view
[image]

I have created a navigation drawer and a Bottom navigation widget, i have face the following problems/

1. While opening drawer it says the drawer exceeds XX pixels so i wrapped it up in "Single child scroll view and now the drawer opens up like a whole page.
2. Also, when drawer is pressed the Bottom navigation overlaps it.
3. I have added images which you can see through my clicking above.

here is my piece of code.

```
    class Mydrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Name'),
                accountEmail: Text('Username'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('Hi'),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text(
                    'Home Page',
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(MyHomepage.route);
                  }),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                title: Text(
                  'My Account',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Account.route);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.assignment),
                title: Text(
                  'My Lists',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Mylist.route);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                title: Text(
                  'Wishlist',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Wishlist.route);
                },
              ),
              Divider(),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.mail),
                title: Text(
                  'Contact us',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Contactus.route);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                title: Text(
                  'Info & FAQ',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Infofaq.route);
                },
              ),
              Divider(),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                title: Text(
                  'Logout',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
Bottom Navigation Code

class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavState createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = [
    NavHome(),
    NavInspiration(),
    NavNotification(),
    NavMessages(),
  ];

  void _onitemtap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: _onitemtap,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_none),
            title: Text('Inspiration'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            title: Text('Notifications'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Main Dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter demo',
      home: Nav(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: Homepage(),
      //initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        MyHomepage.route: (_) => MyHomepage(),
        Account.route: (_) => Account(),
        Mylist.route: (_) => Mylist(),
        Wishlist.route: (_) => Wishlist(),
        Contactus.route: (_) => Contactus(),
        Infofaq.route: (_) => Infofaq(),
      },
    );
  }
}


----------
```

Comment: how do you call both of this classes?

Comment: In the main.dart file i called the Nav() class as under "home:" and created the routes for the drawer. do we have to call both of the classes on main.dart ?

Comment: can i have a look at the main.dart? sorry i cant visualize it in my brain :/

Comment: yes sure, i have added that to the code above

Comment: i have added the image it is overlapping and transparent, please check

Comment: check my answer again, i have edited the codes

Answer (score 0):

> Check this!
>
> [It's work for me](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-vi-navigation-drawer-flutter-1-0-3a05e09b0db9)
>
> use `drawer` part of `scaffold()`.

Comment: Thank you i have tried it and encountered the pixel problem, i have added that image too with my question. please review

Answer (score 0):

i have changed how u relay your codes, try implementing this in your code. and i have decomposed `Nav()`, so take in mind that im not using the `Nav()` as awhole

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MainEntry(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: Homepage(),
      //initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        MyHomepage.route: (_) => MyHomepage(),
        Account.route: (_) => Account(),
        Mylist.route: (_) => Mylist(),
        Wishlist.route: (_) => Wishlist(),
        Contactus.route: (_) => Contactus(),
        Infofaq.route: (_) => Infofaq(),
      },
    );
  }
}


class MainEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainEntryState createState() => _MainEntryState();
}

class _MainEntryState extends State<MainEntry> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: MyDrawer(), 

        body: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex] //your body

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          onTap: _onitemtap,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_none),
            title: Text('Inspiration'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            title: Text('Notifications'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),
        ],
      )
     )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error u are encountering? i have updated the your code in the answer

Comment: if it works as intended, please mark this as answer and upvote! Thanks! :D

Comment: under scaffold i added nav to bottom navigation and it was generating error, and now i have executed your edit. but the condition is same

Comment: Maybe rethink your routing, why are you returning `MaterialApp` in your drawer class? just returning the `SingleChildScrollView` should be fine, if its not then wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` with a Scaffold

Comment: @MukeshBhardwaj try the above code i have just edited

Comment: i trie it but it says undefine name _widgetoptions, selectindex because it is under the scaffold

Comment: then declare it outside the code block, without `_` on the names and amend the dependant in my code with the declared name

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that can be done here is, just like you have your Drawer seperate, create a seperate navbar class with no scaffold or body, just the navbar. Now, call both of these, the drawer and the navbar, in a third widget, which contains your scaffold. For changing the index, you can pass the function as a parameter to your navbar widget.